# Querying Many to Many relationships Entity Framework (doing wrong?? )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I've been doing some research on this topic and figure out a way to achieve this queries in my project but I'm not sure if something here is wrong. please help.

in summary I've created the entities like this:

```
class Student
    {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Courses> Courses {get;set;} //or public List <Courses> {get;set;}
    }
    
    class Course
    {
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Students> Students {get;set;} //or public List<Students> {get;set;}
    }

    // We can see here that the database creates the Join Table Correctly
```

What I want to do:

Display in a grid view each student and for each of the students display the courses in which they are enrolled.

If I made a simple query like

```
dbContex.Students.ToList();
```

and we look at the list the Collection of courses value is null. What is happening here? Shouldn't EF map this and make a query to SQL to get the info?

After this y could not solve the problem because the info that I found was using other approach of the framework (Diagram First, I think) and they set up things in the entities diagram.

How did I work out the problem:

Find out in a WordPress Post a Query that I haven't tried out and add some other lines of code to achieve what I wanted:

```
aux_S = contexto.Students.ToList();

 foreach(var element in aux_S)
         
   {
                
element.Courses= contexto.Courses.Where(c => c.Students.Any(s => s.StudentId == element.StudentId)).ToList();
          
  }
```

// I know I can make a projection to dismiss all the fields that I do not need, this is just to try it out

Am I wrong doing this?

It worked, but how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the slower parts of a database query is the transfer of the data to your machine. So it is good practice to transfer only the data you plan to use.

When you use LINQ in entity framework, using [Queryable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a good way to specify exactly what data you want to transfer. This is usually done just before your final ToList / ToDictionary / FirstOrDefault / Single / ...

You want all Students, each with all his Courses. If you look at your tables, you'll see that there is more data in the tables then you want. For instance, each Student has an Id, each of his Courses have the same value for StudentId. So if a Student attends 20 Courses, you would have transferred the same value for StudentId 21 times.

So to make your query efficient: Select only the Properties of Students you plan to use, with only the Properties of the Courses of these Students you are interested in.

This will automatically solve your problem:

```
var result = myDbcontext.Students

    // if you don't want all Students, use a Where:
    .Where(student => student.City = "Guadalajara")

    // Select only the properties you plan to use:
    .Select(student => new
    {
        Id = student.Id,
        Name = student.Name,
        Birthday = student.Birthday,
        Address = new 
        {
            Street = student.Street,
            City = student.City,
            ...
         }

         Courses = student.Courses
             // if you don't want all courses: use a where
             .Where(course => course.Start.Year == 2018)
             // again: select only the properties you plan to use
             {
                  Name = course.Name,
                  Location = course.Location,
                  ...
                  // One of the useless properties to transfer:
                  // StudentId = course.StudentId
              })
              .ToList();
      });
```

Comment: Thank you alot you relly helped mi with this proyections, so i'm right saying that LINQ is only going to query what i ask for??

Answer (score 0):

You are not lazy loading, if you add `virtual` like: `public virtual ICollection<Courses> Courses {get;set;}` you should get the courses loaded.

However, I'd advise using lazy loading since it may cause performance issues down the road, what you want to do is eager loading.

So when you are querying your student you would simply do this:
`dbContex.Students.Include(c => c.Courses).ToList();`

Comment: that you soo much you guys are really helping me to improve my self on this!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: also    ` dbContex.Include(c => c.Courses).Students.ToList(); `

   in here shoulden't i tell the dbcontext wich table first because if i write  `dbContex.Include() ` we have an error

Comment: Ah my bad, I just wrote it on top of my head. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah but thanks.. i also read that to use the lambda insted of the magic string we use **system.data.entity**

Comment: I don't follow, `.Include(c => c.Courses)` is lambda, and it's under the namespace of `System.Data.Entity`. What you are referring to is `.Include("Courses");`

Comment: i I expressed wrong i was trying
 to say what you did thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform this query:

```
var studentslist = dbContex.Students.ToList();
```

Each item on studentslist will have the 'Courses' collection null, because, although the connection/relation exists (between each table), you didn't specify that you wanted that collection populated. For that to happen you can change your query accordingly:

```
var studentslist = dbContex.Students.Include(p => p.Courses).ToList();
```

Now, after running the last query, if you get an empty list on one/any of the items, then it means those items (students), aren't linked to any courses.

Comment: Of course i was thinking kind of doing that but didn't remember how to do it cause i've seen it a while ago.

Comment: So for me to add a new student and do the link to the correct course first i have to load the courses table into my context to let the ChangeTracker be aware that the courses id's that i set up to this new student already exisist in the database and then how do i assign it ??? i guess i could fill the collection of courses just in there and with the id's the join table will know about it ???

Comment: @CarlosEcheverriaSt sorry, could you please explain yourself better? I'm a little confused. Didn't quite get what you meant.